# SIGABRT when switching views Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, view

```
-(IBAction)enterVeryBasics:(id)sender {
  VeryBasics *enterIntro = [[VeryBasics alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
  [self presentModalViewController:enterIntro animated:YES];
  [enterIntro release];
}
```

I have this code here, and on `[self presentModalViewController:enterIntro animated:YES];` it's giving me a SIGABRT

I have multiple other actions in the same .m file, but they aren't having the same problem.

Comment: Do you mean to pass the 'nil' as the nib name? Or in your code does it include the specific filename?

Comment: it would help if you included the error, SIGABRT often include information on what caused the problem.

Comment: `[enterIntro release];` is too early there. You have to do `dismissModalViewController` some time later, than release it.

Comment: @ott: Not true, the view controller gets retained by `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Whats the comment with the Sigbrt. Sigbrt errors appears only when u are trying to call a method which is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at UIViewController Class reference instance method signature:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Is your VeryBasics is Subclass of UIViewController ? It doesn't look like from your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
VeryBasics *enterIntro = [[VeryBasics alloc]init];
 self presentModalViewController:enterIntro animated:YES];
[enterIntro release];
```

Use this if you dont have nib so dont need of initWithNibName.